# Using google play expansion files

Tags: android, google-play, apk-expansion-files

I've just finished an app which is about 100MB and I need to use expansion files for the first time.

I've looked through this tutorial http://ankitthakkar90.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/apk-expansion-files-in-android-with.html, but I don't understand the concept of expansion files and looking for a bit more clarification.

1. What exactly are the contents of these expansion files? For example my app using alot of images and videos are these what need to go in my expansion files.
2. If the above is correct does that mean I need to take them out of my project, change my code were I have referenced these resources directly from my drawables and instead reference them from memory?
3. If both the above are wrong then what exactly goes in the expansion files and what happens to the apk which is already over 50MB.

I'd really appreciate any help explaining this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Expansion files can have any assets that you use in your app (videos,audio,images,text files etc).

2) Yes, your expansion files are extracted inside the external storage of the device.. you should update all your references to get the data from there.

http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html

The above link has it all explained (naming to use, how to debug ) etc.

Comment: Alright so basically I need to take out all resources in my expansion file from my project so my apk is at most 50MB and get everything else from expansion files.